# unable to pass datatable row index when using default enter key

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I am unable to pass the correct row index from a datatable where I default the enter key using keycode 13. If I construct a commandButton and manually press it, it gets the correct input.

In the examples below, you can see I've tried to get this working about 10 different ways. I've tried calling a remote command from onkeypress = 13 that do the following:
- pass the index to the backing bean -  always uses index 0
- pass the index to the backing bean using binding table.rowIndex -  always uses index 0
- passing current row var - always uses last entry in list
- passing wrapped ListDataModel a - always uses index 0

Then I tried constructing buttons each with a unique styleclass and calling a javascript funtion to click the correct button. That alwasy uses index 0.

I also tried using a defaultCommand - always uses last index

So, the question is, how do I get this to work???

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
>

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:form id="formId" >
<h:body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function saveButton(myIndex) {
            var id = '.saveButton' + myIndex;
            var ele = $(id).get(0);
            console.info("*** id " + id + " ele " + ele);
            ele.click();
        }
    </script>


    <p:panel id="messagesId">
        <p:growl id="growlMessageId" showDetail="false" autoUpdate="true" for="growl"/>
        <p:messages id="messageId" showDetail="false" autoUpdate="true" for="messages"/>
    </p:panel>

    <p:dataTable id="wordsId" var="word" value="#{wordIndexBean.words}"
                 rowKey="#{wordIndexBean.words}"
                 rowIndexVar="index"
                 editable="true" editMode="cell"
                 style="width:620px;height:400px"
                 emptyMessage="Your words go here"
                 binding="#{table}">
        <p:column headerText="Modify">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{word}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Modify" width="275px">
            <!--always returns last word in list-->
            <p:remoteCommand name="remoteWordEnter" update="wordsId"
                             action="#{wordIndexBean.modifyWordAction(word)}"/>
            <!--always finds first/0 word in model-->
            <p:remoteCommand name="remoteWordEnterModel" update="wordsId"
                             action="#{wordIndexBean.modifyWordActionModel}"/>
            <!--always uses index 0-->
            <p:remoteCommand name="remoteIndexEnterIndex" update="wordsId"
                             action="#{wordIndexBean.modifyWordActionIndex(index)}"/>
            <!--always uses first index 0-->
            <p:remoteCommand name="remoteIndexEnterIndex2" update="wordsId"
                             action="#{wordIndexBean.modifyWordActionIndex(table.rowIndex)}"/>
<!--
            <p:inputText id="inputId" value="#{wordIndexBean.modifyWord}" style="width:96%"
            onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { remoteWordEnterIndex2(); return false; }"/>  
-->
            <!-- Following test calls javascript function. JS gets correct index but button always calls with 0 index -->
            <p:inputText id="inputId2" value="#{wordIndexBean.modifyWord}" style="width:96%"
                         onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { saveButton(#{index});}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column width="20px">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="index"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{index}" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column width="20px">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="action"/>
            </f:facet>
            <!--<p:defaultCommand target="save"/> -->
            <!-- DefaultCommand always uses last index, using button manually works -->
            <h:commandButton id="save" styleClass="saveButton{index}" value="Save #{index}"
                             action="#{wordIndexBean.modifyWordActionIndex(index)}"/>
            <h:commandButton id="save2" styleClass="save2Button{index}" value="Save2 #{table.rowIndex}"
                             action="#{wordIndexBean.modifyWordActionIndex(table.rowIndex)}"/>
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>


</h:body>
</h:form>
</html>
```

Backing Bean

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class WordIndexBean {
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(WordIndexBean.class);
private String modifyWord;
private List<String> words;
private ListDataModel<String> wrappedWords = new ListDataModel<>();


public WordIndexBean() {
    words = new ArrayList<>();
    words.add("word1");
    words.add("word2");
    words.add("word3");
}

public void modifyWordAction(String word) {
    logger.info("word "+word);
    this.modifyWord = null;
}

public void modifyWordActionModel() {
    String word = getWrappedWords().getRowData();
    int rowIndex = getWrappedWords().getRowIndex();

    logger.info("word "+word+ " index "+rowIndex);
    this.modifyWord = null;
}

public void modifyWordActionIndex(int rowIndex) {
        logger.info("index "+rowIndex);
        this.modifyWord = null;
    }

public String getModifyWord() {
    return modifyWord;
}

public void setModifyWord(String modifyWord) {
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(modifyWord)) {
        this.modifyWord = modifyWord;
    }
}

public List<String> getWords() {
    return words;
}

public ListDataModel<String> getWrappedWords() {
    wrappedWords.setWrappedData(getWords());
    return wrappedWords;
}

public void setWrappedWords(ListDataModel<String> wrappedWords) {
    this.wrappedWords = wrappedWords;
}

}
```

Comment: Don't put the remote commands in the column tag. That creates multiple javascript functions with most likely weird behaviour and can explain the 0 or last you see used. And you do not describe what the (dynamic?) default should be. I kind of do not understand what you actually want to achieve. There can only be one default button...

Comment: And why do you use binding? And why pass the binding value rowIndexvar `table.rowIndex` and not just the `index` as defined in `rowIndexVar="index"`?

Comment: Do not know if it helps to your problem, but just as a remark: Your buttons styleClass values will always be the same _saveButton{item}_ and _save2Button{item}_ because you missed the **number sign**, hence your jquery selector will not find any of them.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried moving remoteCommand from the column tag. It had to go outside the table. To make it work, I still would need to pass the current index from the column to the remoteCommand. I followed some examples but that did not work as well.

Comment: <p:remoteCommand name="remoteIndexEnterParam" update="wordsId"
                         action="#{wordIndexBean.modifyWordActionParam}"/>
        <p:dataTable id="wordsId" var="word" value="#{wordIndexBean.words}"
                     rowKey="#{wordIndexBean.words}"  rowIndexVar="index">
           <p:column headerText="Modify">
                <p:inputText id="inputId" value="#{wordIndexBean.modifyWord}"
                             onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { remoteIndexEnterParam({param: 'value'});  }"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

Comment: public void modifyWordActionParam() {
        String value = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("param");
        logger.info(" value "+value);
    }

Comment: re the binding, that was just to try somethng else. And correct on the missing numberSign. Sorry for the lack of formatting in my example to pass parameter.